# cupy convolve not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, cupy

I am trying to get cupy to use convolve from the doc here
https://docs.cupy.dev/en/latest/reference/generated/cupy.convolve.html

```
>>> import cupy as cp
>>> b = cp.array([0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1])
>>> cp.convolve(b, cp.ones(3), 'same') / 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'cupy' has no attribute 'convolve'
```

So convolve on numpy seems to work but not with cupy.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1])
>>> np.convolve(a, np.ones(3), 'same') / 3
array([0.        , 0.        , 0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333,
       0.        , 0.33333333, 0.33333333])
```

Although basic functions like add work with cupy.

```
>>> cp.add(b, b)
array([0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2], dtype=int32)
```

Setup:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
- cuda 11.0.3 451.82
- cuDNN 11.0 x64 v8.0.3.33
- cuTENSOR 1.2.0

pip:

- numpy-1.19.1
- cupy-cuda110-7.8.0
- optuna-2.0.0

I made clean new installation of Python and cuda, ..., but that did not solve the problem.
I am now out of idea what still could be missing. As far as I have understood is cupy, just numpy processed on the gpu, so every function of numpy should be in cupy.

Comment: I  might have found the problem the docs are for latest and my cupy version is 7.8.0 where convolve is not mentioned. I have a look if I can upgrade to that.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems cupy 7.8.0 does not support convolve, only at version 8.0.0
So I now installed the current release candidate cupy_cuda110-8.0.0rc1

```
pip install --pre -U cupy-cuda110
```

Now convolve works fine

Comment: In order to upgrade the cupy version, it seems I also need to upgrade my cuda version from 10.1 to 11. But if I am also using tensorflow for gpu, then I need to use cuda 10.1 currently for it to work according to tensorflow. By any chance, are you also using tensorflow at all?

Comment: @JeffBoker I am not using tenserflow. But the newest cupy versions are also available for other cuda versions like 10.1 https://pypi.org/project/cupy-cuda101/#history